# Register user product review not reflecting in My account section

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, review

If any register user (already logged in) write any product review it submitted successfully. but In My account section, My product reviews is empty.

Any clue why reviews are not assigning to logged in user?

Comment: Make sure you approve the review. Only approved reviews show up in frontend.

Comment: Do any reviews show in `Admin > Catalog > Reviews and Ratings > Customer Reviews > All Reviews`. Is the reviewer info empty?

Comment: approved reviews are visible in front end ie product page but MY account -> My product reviews -> reviews are not vissible  and I can see all reviews in admin. In admin -> reports-> customer reviews I can't see any review but  in admin -> reports -> product reviews i can see all reviews.

Comment: How I can debug review module?

Comment: @ganesh Are you sure the reviews were submitted as Customer and not Guest? Are they listed as such at `Admin > Catalog > Reviews and Ratings > Customer Reviews > All Reviews` under `Type` column?

Comment: Reviewer is guest in all reviews even reviews submitted by register user.

Comment: That is your problem. Only reviews associated with a customer will be visible in the customer account. Your question now is - why are all users treated as Guest?

Comment: Ok but everything related to register user is working fine,
My account, Cart, checkout etc. Then why its not working with reviews? What exactly I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Only reviews that are approved and were submitted by registered users (a Customer) will be visible in the customer account under `My Product Reviews`.

In the admin grid `Admin > Catalog > Reviews and Ratings > Customer Reviews > All Reviews`, the `Type` column will either show **Customer** or **Guest**.

Your reviews are not visible in the user's account because they were posted as a Guest. Your question now becomes why are all user's treated as guests when it comes to reviews?

You can try to turn off the admin option `Allow Guests to Write Reviews` and see what happens when you try to leave a review as a Customer:

`Admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Product Reviews`

There is a known bug relating to this too: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/53641/

Hope that helps.

Comment: If Allow Guests to Write Reviews is off then all reviews are assigned to one specific user no matter who post review. And this is strange, all reviews assigned to user whos customer_id is 1. So I play around customer_entity table -> entity_id column ie customer_id. If I change customer id 1 to any user then review assign to this new user. IF I remove customer_id 1 at all then reviewer is blank.

Comment: I tried both solution provided in link but Its not working for me. Still all reviews assign to customer_id 1.

Comment: The problem clearly relates to your specific installation, not Magento in general. Have you got many 3rd party extensions installed? It sounds like the session is being altered in some way.